# IOUtils: is it required to close OutputStream?

Tags: java, apache-commons, outputstream

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13325663/5829191), a guy suggested using `IOUtils.copy` but he did not close OutputStream. Here's his example:

```
InputStream is = new URL(imgUrl).openStream();
OutputStream os = servletResponse.getOutputStream();

IOUtils.copy(is, os);
is.close();
```

I checked javadocs for the `copy` method in IOUtils and there is no information that OutputStream will be closed automaticaly so I'm curious is it required to close OutputStream in that sample?

Comment: If you do intend to close your resource or steam, make sure to call `close()` from within a `finally` block to make sure that it gets executed at all times. Alternatively, open your resource in a [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IOUtils.copy(InputStream, OutputStream)` must not close the `OutputStream`. You can use it for example to concatenate different `InputStreams` and in this case it would be a bad idea if it would close the provided Input- and/or OutputStream.

As a rule of thumb any method should close only those steams it opens.
See also [Should I close the servlet outputstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829784/should-i-close-the-servlet-outputstream)

Answer (score 1):

As you say, [the documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream)) says nothing about closing the `OutputStream` for you, so you need to close it (explicitly, or by using try-with-resources).

The reason [Tomasz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/605744/tomasz-nurkiewicz) didn't close the stream in that answer was that it's the output stream of a servlet response. As [andih](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1317117/andih) said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38419378/ioutils-is-it-required-to-close-outputstream/38419393?noredirect=1#comment64245885_38419393), you only close streams you *open*. The servlet container manages the servlet response stream.

Comment: **Don't** close the OutputStream of a ServletResponse. You should only close Streams you've opened. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829784/should-i-close-the-servlet-outputstream

Comment: Indeed, a quick glance at the source code *confirms* that `IOUtils.copy` does NOT close either stream.