# Java ZK full path to WebContent/img

Tags: java, file, path, zk

i have a array of bytes store in disk using `ZK Framework` later i need to retrieve this array of bytes and create a file `the real file` i need later pass it to the a gallery on image using `Javascript jquery plugin` which uses the following pattern to show the images.

```
<h:a href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/46/Bohinjsko_jezero_2.jpg/800px-Bohinjsko_jezero_2.jpg">
<h:img                     src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/46/Bohinjsko_jezero_2.jpg/100px-Bohinjsko_jezero_2.jpg"/>
```

what have i solved so far?

i have create the file using the array of bytes using `CommonsIO` is OK. i was wondering if java7 have a mehod to create the file from a `arrayofBytes` which is not important for now.

as you can see the main important thing here is the plugin needs to source to my file image

```
<h:img                    src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/46/Bohinjsko_jezero_2.jpg/100px-Bohinjsko_jezero_2.jpg"/>
```

i have create a file in `temp directory` but this directory is unreacheable to the browser i guess because is firing an error **image not found** my solution is to create the `file image` inside image folder inside `WEBCONTENT/image` folder which it works using static images my question is..

how can i get the full path to my app directory programmatically? something like

```
C:\app\eclipse\myproject\WebContent\img\temporals
```

for later to create here the `temporal file`

there is a better approach i only have the array of bytes of the image at start..

thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is *faux pas* to write data, during the lifetime of your web application, to the web application directory itself. It's even worse to try to reference these files by their path. These files will be deleted when the application is redeployed and in a servlet container you rarely reference files by their actual path, you reference the servlet's path.

Depending on your setup, you probably don't need to write the file to the disk at all. In the end, your server needs to read that file and stream it to the client anyway.

Your best option is probably to provide a servlet which just streams back the byte array with the [correct mime type](http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml) (eg: image/jpeg).
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417695/1906491) suggests something similar.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2980313/1906491) discusses implementation.
This is ideal in your case if you're working with the byte array anyway.

Another option, leveraging ZK, would be to create an [AImage](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/image/AImage.html) with the byte array and [render that directly](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/Image.html#setContent(org.zkoss.image.Image)).

You can also consider serving static content from your server (probably not straight forward if you're using a servlet container like Tomcat) or use a simpler server like Apache Server for hosting your images.

It's tough to recommend anything specifically without knowing the context of your question.

Comment: but i need the src of the image in both the `a` and `img` tag because is the way the `javascript image plugin` can handle the gallery and well their image zoomer also i can't use AImage because the image will not be handle it by ZK it will handle by Javascript..

Comment: That's fair. Still, go with the servlet approach. It's the standard approach to serving up data in a servlet container (which I assume you're using as you mentioned using ZK as a front end).

Comment: yes i can set the image using the servlet but i need the Source in <a> tag because with this the image is zoomed when is clicked.... how can i solved this. thanks a lot

Comment: You *serve* the image using the servlet. Your `<a>` tag would then be `<a href="/myproject/images/cool.png"><img src="/myproject/image/cool.png"/></a>` where `images/` is a servlet which returns the given image, regardless of it's location on disk. Read through the linked answers.

Comment: mmmm i dont understand very clear you said.. that cool.png is the image itself?? but i dont have the src or you said the cool.png is the servlet which serves the image??