# Linking Files And Directory Structuring

Tags: java, css, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I'm working on a web project using **java/ jsp/ servlets/ html/ css** in eclipse tomcat, where everything is in the WebContent folder.

In my jsp files... When I try to include other jsp files (using a link like "/fileName.jsp" in jsp include directive) I can do that successfully.
But When I try to include image files (using a link like "/fileName.jpg" in the `<img src="">` tag) nothing happens.
Nothing happens because instead of looking in the WebContent folder for image file it looks in the tomcat home directory, i.e.
Instead of looking at "**http ://localhost:port/projectName/...**" it looks at "**http: //localhost:port/...**"
Why does it look at the wrong location only with `<img src="">` tags but not in `<%@ />` tag.

A workaround for this is that I start giving absolute paths "**/projectName/...**" However doing this means I'm hardcoding project name everywhere. This is what I do not want.

Comment: Please post some concise code showing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Don't include binary content in an ascii output. Why not just use the `img` tag? If you need to do something to produce a jpeg, I would use a Servlet.

Comment: Using a servlet to produce a jpeg is unknown to me. Can you elaborate, or post some links?

Comment: Here is a [link](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-05-2000/jw-0505-servlets.html) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979758/writing-image-to-servlet-response-with-best-performance) is [another](http://www.codebeach.com/2008/02/creating-images-in-java-servlet.html).

Answer (score 0):

Because the jsp-Links in the website are getting processed and the image links not. Either change the image path or develop an filter that changes the images'links.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Templar, that could have been a way to solve my problem.

However, I simply changed the Context Root of my project from "Project Name" to "/" in Eclipse. This solved my problem.