# How to send Data from Tomcat Server to Client?

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat, transfer

I need to write a function that gets a Json via Spring and deliver a Data. The case is that a customer is sending me a Filename and im looking in a database where the file is and send him the data. I only need a little kickstart and someone who can answer me to my Questions:

- Do I really need Sockets for this?
- What for a Stream I should use (Its several Datatypes likes Pictures,
  Documents, Pdf....)
- How can I identify the Destination to send

Comment: You could just send the data as a response to the incoming request, if that's acceptable for you?

Comment: Yes that would be right but how can i realize that ? Thank you for yoru answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Response like this :

```
String yourData;
JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(response.getWriter());
    writer.beginObject();
    writer.name("data").value(yourData);
    writer.endObject();
    writer.close();
```

Comment: Is that rly so easy?  my data can be an Image or else. Will the Download windows appear when im doing this ? Excuse my Questions but im very new to File stuff.

Comment: it's just a simple example to make ideas  
you cas see this for image 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979758/writing-image-to-servlet-response-with-best-performance