# need a servlet to download a file from path like /home/Bureau

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, gwt, download

Need a servlet to download a file from path like /home/Bureau.. in jee gwt 
I used this but isn't work
and I went to download all file's type image

```
 String filePath = request.getParameter("file");
    String fileName = "test";
 FileInputStream fileToDownload = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    //   ServletOutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");
      //response.setContentType("image/png");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + ".png\"");
 //                        response.setContentLength(fileToDownload.available());

    int readBytes = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
    while ((readBytes = fileToDownload.read(buffer, 0, 10000)) != -1) {
        //output.write(readBytes);
        response.getOutputStream().write(readBytes);
    }

    response.getOutputStream().close();
    fileToDownload.close();
    fileToDownload.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is at below line where you are writing no of bytes not actual bytes. Here `readBytes` represents no of bytes read at a time where as `buffer` contains actual bytes that is read.

```
response.getOutputStream().write(readBytes);
```

---

Try

```
OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

while ((readBytes = fileToDownload.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    outputStream.write(buffer,0,readBytes);
}

outputStream.close();
```

---

I suggest you to call `response.getOutputStream()` single time.

Your code will give you `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the size of the file is less than 10000 bytes because of below line

```
 fileToDownload.read(buffer, 0, 10000)
```

Change it to

```
fileToDownload.read(buffer)
```

---

Use `ServletContext` to get file path.

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
```

For more info have a look at below posts:

[Writing image to servlet response with best performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979758/writing-image-to-servlet-response-with-best-performance?answertab=votes#tab-top).

[How do I return an image from a servlet using ImageIO?](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-return-an-image-from-a-servlet-using-imageio.html)