# SmartGWT/GWT: Show a PDF on client side

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I have an already generated PDF on my server-side,I would like some help on showing the pdf when clicking a button on the client side.

How should I create the conextion with the server and client using the shared?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a servlet and call it from client side on clicking a button.

```
String servletName = GWT.getModuleBaseURL().replace("/" + GWT.getModuleName(), "")
                     + "pdf_download_servlet";
Window.open(servletName, "", "");
```

For a servlet code please have a look at [need a servlet to download a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23110475/need-a-servlet-to-download-a-file-from-path-like-home-bureau/23111844#23111844).

Comment: Can you explain me more about servlet? Please... I don't get how it works.

Comment: Follow this link [How do I return an image from a servlet using ImageIO?](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-return-an-image-from-a-servlet-using-imageio.html) and read all the pages.