# SmartGwt: Show PDF in a vLayout

Tags: pdf, client, smartgwt

I need to open a PDF in the client. 
The PDF its generated in my Controller (i have no problem with that) and i need to show that PDF inside a layout (not a window).

Related: [SmartGWT/GWT: Show a PDF on client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23254196/smartgwt-gwt-show-a-pdf-on-client-side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could show the pdf in a SmartGWT component using an IFrame.

See [this sample](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#basics_html_load_pages) and [this forum](http://forums.smartclient.com/forum/smart-gwt-technical-q-a/6339-pdf-viewer-panel).

Comment: It worked, but i needed this in my server controller;  resp.setContentType("application/pdf"); resp.setContentLength(ficheroPDF.length); resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=stats.pdf");