# How to display a default image when image source is a servlet?

Tags: java, html, image, jsp, servlets

In my JSP/ Servlet setup, for displaying user profile images I am directing the `img` tag to get the image from servlet by specifying servlet URL in `src` tag and then returning image in response from servlet.

Sevlet does below things upon receiving an image request,

1. It gets the image from database in `BLOB` format
2. Prepares image from the `byte`[] and
3. returns the image in `response` object with appropriate headers.

My problem is since Signup page doesn't has image upload option so new users don't have their image in database i.e. so the `BLOB` is `NULL`. **How can I display a default image for all such users ?**

**EDIT**
Based on comments received I just wanted to note that. I am aware of the solutions where we set the default value either in database (while creating the user) or return the default image array when there is NULL in database. **I am already using the later case.** By this question I just wanted to discuss about **any other possible solutions**.

Comment: Have you tried creating and storing a default image in the database for "new users" ?

Comment: That sounds logical but I think their should be some other solution  as well, instead of loading the database with lot of default images.

Comment: You can try to do this in several ways, example You can try to download user-defined picture, if its null you're downloading default picture ;)

Comment: Save a default user picture in your EAR/WAR and if database in returning NULL then return that default user picture in response.

Comment: @Amit, I didn't mean that you should upload "lots" of default images, only 1 is needed. It would then be possible for you to create a `SELECT` statement that returns the users image or the default image if the users current value is null. Look up the SQL command `ISNULL`. If the statement is created correctly, this will also work for unregistered users as well.

Comment: @munyul thanks for the explanation. Than this sounds gr8. However still overhead of an additional where condition can't be ignored. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to return HTTP error 404 "Not found" when the user don't have an image. It seems quite logical to me, since there really is no image for the user.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
}
```

Then in your HTML you can handle this case using the [onerror Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp) to set the default image:

```
<img src="servletUrl" onerror="this.src='default.png'" width="150" height="150" />
```

In this way the servlet only sends user images and does not do any special logic if the user doesn't have one.

Comment: Thanks @Tobias.. This is exactly what I am looking for. Will give another day to question before accepting your answer. May be some one comes up with even better solution.